# Connecting to Snowflake using Node.js using federated authentication

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Our Snowflake environment integration is enabled with Federated authentication using OKTA.

We are able to connect to Snowflake from Python using the below parameters. Whereas from the Node.js server, we don't see an option to pass the authenticator option.

```
accountname = xxxxx.west-us-2.azure

region = west-us-2.azure

username = yyy_xxxx_rrrr

password = "sdsdsdsdsds"

dbname = SAMPLE_DB

schemaname = STT

rolename = GBB_CREATE

warehousename = GBB_COMPUTE1

proxy_host = proxy.****.com

proxy_port = 80

**authenticator = "https://XXXXX.okta.com/"**
```

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/nodejs-driver-use.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SSO authentication is not supported for NodeJS driver, only for SnowSQL, Python connector, JDBC and ODBC drivers. For more information have a look here:

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/admin-security-fed-auth-use.html#using-sso-with-client-applications-that-connect-to-snowflake